# Is it possible to develop C# projects in Visual Studio and then compile in SharpDevelop?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sharpdevelop

Is there any incomparability between Visual Studio and SharpDevelop projects?

P.S. For Windows Forms applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think SharpDevelop supports msbuild now, so there shouldn't be much problems:

> "SharpDevelop 2.0 uses the same
>   MSBuild project files as Visual
>   Studio"

Comment: +1 last time I checked, SharpDevelop did not support "web site" projects though

Answer (score 1):

As long as SharpDevelop compiles for .net and not for mono it uses the same compiler as Visual Studio (which is integrated in .net itself), so there shouldn't be any incompatibilities

Comment: Actually, Visual Studio doesn't use the compiler that is part of the framework.  See this:  http://blogs.msdn.com/ed_maurer/archive/2008/06/11/a-tale-of-two-compilers.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For one thing : it does supports sln files. That of course doesn't mean there are no incompatibilities at all..

Answer (score 1):

SharpDevelop loads VS.NET solution files (and as a result proj files) as I'm aware and so is fully compatible when it comes to loading your 'standard' VS.NET solutions.